# server timeout issue

Tags: web-services, apache, tomcat

I am using `tk10x` server to listen some request from a `GPS` device on my `OpenGTS` server. By default this tk10x has a timeout of 60000ms. I want to remove this timeout thing what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few texts from: http://www.opengts.org/FAQ.html

#### For Tomcat

> This can be changed in the Tomcat default "web.xml" file found in the Tomcat directory "$CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml". Here is the section of the "web.xml" file that sets the timeout to 30 minutes:

```
 <session-config>
     <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
```

> You can change this value to any desired length of time. Tomcat should be restarted after this value has been changed. (Note: setting this value too large may cause excessive resources to be consumes by users which have logged in, but are not actually using the system).

#### Alternative

> This can be configured in the "dcservers.xml" file (or "dcservers/dcserver_XXXXX.xml" file where XXXXX is the DCS id) by setting the TCP timeout values to '0', as follows:

```
<Property key="tcpIdleTimeoutMS">0</Property>
<Property key="tcpPacketTimeoutMS">0</Property>
<Property key="tcpSessionTimeoutMS">0</Property>
```

> This will cause the DCS (where the above properties were set) to always leave the TCP session open. (Note: each connected TCP connesion consumes system resources - memory, threads, filehandles, etc. Having many such connected TCP sessions may significantly limit the number of devices which can connect with your server).